# What are the legitimate domains of humanitarian action?

Tags: ethics, applied-philosophy

I was wondering if there are domains where Humanitarian organizations could totally justify their interventions, in opposite of course with those where they couldn't. What intrigued me was the French NGO "Télécoms sans frontières", which mission is to provide humanitarian help through ICT (Information and Communication Technologies). It's quite unusual, and some would say that it's almost at the fringe of what can be done in the frame of NGOs interventions, but why could they say that?

Is it possible that NGOs' legitimacy is more prevalent in a medical field, or for interventions in food crisis, or can they intervene in any domain, as long as they provide an actual help and an improvement of the living conditions? Can it be considered ethically wrong, typically like interference, that NGOs intervene in some domains that are not considered to be within their scope?

I'm asking this question from a standpoint of the helper, and what he can do to improve the life of the one he helps. What are the boundaries of such an help, and especially when it's so widely organized as in an NGO?

Comment: What system of ethics do you wish to apply?  A system of ethics which is based around the will of a deity will permit different boundaries than a utilitarian system of ethics will.  Setting such boundaries is tricky to word.  Even the word "NGO" is tricky.  To quote wikipedia: "NGOs are difficult to define, and the term 'NGO' is rarely used consistently"

Comment: As the comment before mine already asked, what exactly do you mean when you write "justify" or "ethically wrong"? Why, if I may ask, did this question arise, anyway? For me it is hard to see why humanitarian help would ever be ethically wrong, but maybe that depends upon definitions of help and humanitarian, too...

Comment: @iphigenie In fact, it could be ethically wrong when it puts the sovereignty at stake, like in interference. It can be wrong, but when is a question yet unanswered, because even interference is unclear.

Comment: @CortAmmon I don't refer to NGOs nominally, I'd rather think about humanitarian help in a global and unfocused way, and ask the question of its scope: is it limitless, can humanitarian agents help in any way possible, or is it restricted and on what grounds if it's the case?

Comment: @iphigenie "justify" because help must be legitimate, it must have grounds to stand on, to prove it's useful, because it's an action on a foreign soil (hence the problem of interference).

Comment: Without moral justifications and humanities sense of current "right" ethics, there would be no sense in compassion.

Comment: Based on the lack of clarity as to what ethical framework should be used for answering the question (and the corresponding answers), I'm closing this question as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

**It is usually accepted that an actor acting in a ethically unambiguous way is ethical; however, while your question leads to such tautologies it is clear this is not the answer you are seeking.**

All actions are deemed ethical or not by some source of ethics.  That may be an ethical code written by a nation, an ethical code in the name of all of humanity, or even the "natural code of ethics" written into the universe (if one chooses to believe in such a thing).

I think the major challenge you are facing with the wording of your question is the term "humanitarian help."  By its namesake alone, this suggests that the actions to be undertaken are in the name of humanity itself, which is a very high cause to question.  However, there are countless religious positions which "defend humanity from itself" which claim a higher calling.  In this sense, **every action for any cause can have its ethics questioned by someone who claims all ethics derives from their deity, and those questions will be accepted by an individual proportional to their belief in that deity.**

We also have to consider the well known grey area of intent vs. effect.  How much does it matter that you seek to "undertake actions in the name of humanity" if your actions do not align with that goal?  Few would suggest a "humanitarian" has ethical carte blanche to assassinate a world leader in the name of humanity.  This is a classic issue which stems from our need to act on partial information, when the final action is often judged on the full information available at a later time.  **Whether a humanitarian group's ethical right to act is determined by their intent or their actions is not clear cut.**

You clearly have stated an issue with such humanitarian interests interfering with sovereignty.  **The right for any group to act without bounds is wholly set in the particular ethical code you bound them to.**  Take any humanitarian event which challenges sovereignty, it is trivial to set up two ethical stances: one which condemns the event and one which extols it.

Consider: in one of your comments, you state that "... help must be legitimate, it must have grounds to stand on, to prove it's useful, because it's an action on foreign soil."  It is trivial to create a dual to that position: "A state must constantly legitimize its actions, it must have grounds to stand on, to prove it's useful; because it's an action within humanity."  It is not trivial to distinguish which position is more correct.

As you have not specified an ethical system to discuss, the only code which does not have such a dual is the natural code, a.k.a. the universal code of ethics.  It is not entirely agreed whether one exists; it is *certainly* not agreed on what the code contains, if it does exist.  All we have are individual philosopher's interpretations of what a universal code of ethics "would have to contain."

Consider a humanitarian aid troupe whose mission is "to provide humanitarian aid by teaching children in impoverished countries to read."  It would be reasonable to argue that such efforts should have unlimited scope because they support all of humanity, *but you would first have to defend why literacy is more important to "humanity" than anything else*.  If you can make such a defense, then no nation can ethically intervene.  If you can make the counterargument that the structure provided by a [potentially oppressive] government's sovereignty is more important than literacy, then it is trivial to show that nations can ethically intervene.

**You cannot make a global statement about all humanitarian aid in all conditions in all nations in all systems of ethics without weakening the statement to mere tautologies.  If you focus on one class of actions by one group in one nation at one point in time, you stand a chance of discussing the ethical nature of their actions with things resembling truths and facts.**

Answer (score 0):

You want to first off note the difference between legal extent and morality.

Lets consider the NGO as an agent then, a person. If I as a person wish to offer aid to another group, then I think I ought be free to, as long as they are **informed** and I do not **exploit** them.

Then we have the whole national / state / geopolitical framework that potentially undermines and underscores that... which drifts into sociology.